# How to Build Horizontal Slider Animation on Vertical Scroll in React Js

Tags: css, reactjs, animation, material-ui

I am trying to build a sliding animation on a landing page, The functionality I am trying to build is as follows.

When a user lands on a landing page they should see the div which will contain an image and content and when they scroll the divs should slide horizontally once the specified divs are finished they should continue to the remaining page.

I have the reference below.

https://ivang-design.com/euthenia/

Thank You

Comment: You did this because I need same.